# How to remove the padding of images into horizontal linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, padding

I´m using the xml code for the horizontal linearlayout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back1"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:src="@drawable/ca_18"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the ImageView have a padding top and bottom. How can I remove the padding?

Comment: This is probably because your height attribute isn't wrap_content

Comment: I changed to android:layout_height="match_parent" (in the ImageView) and nothing change

Answer (score 2):

Avoid hardcoding the layout_height and layout_width attributes. This may look fine on your device. But may look ugly on another.